# Convert Bitbucket to Youtrack

Tags: bitbucket, issue-tracking, youtrack

I have my issue tracker setup with Bitbucket.org, is there a way to import from Bitbucket to local YouTrack or on-demand YouTrack issue tracking?

Comment: @ThanksBro nope I had to do it manually :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to write a script that moves issues from bitbucket from youtrack using their REST APIs. You can write it really quickly and, as a bonus, you'll gain a bit of insight into your new tool. ;)

"Easy" because normally when switching from a system to another you have to convert values (maybe your own conventions) and/or clean up stuff (maybe I don't want to move everything)...

[Bitbucket REST API documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/issues+Resource)

[YouTrack REST API documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/YouTrack+REST+API+Reference)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue just few days ago and I did not found some implementation using the APIs as @Manuel suggested. Writing my own started to take more time than I wanted to invest. So the solution I came up at the end was:

[JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) have a nice import wizard that allow you to easily import data from many other issue trackers (BitBucket included). It also have a free trial period.

YouTrack have integration for importing data from JIRA. That's all I've got to say.